# OAuth two-legged with JWT and refresh_token

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, jwt

I am implementing the authorization and authentication flow for an API. I was thinking of two-legged OAuth (as the API is only going to be used by us, not third-party applications). But I found some problems regarding to tokens and their expiration periods.

I would request an access_token to **/ouath/token** with the username and password of the user. This endpoint should return an JWT as access_token.

Next requests to the API will use that JWT to authenticate the user.

JWT's are supposed to expiry in a period time (1 day for example). I have read I need to implement a refresh endpoint in which the app could refresh the JWT in order no to ask the user for username and password every day.

So, ¿how could I generate that refresh_token? JWT's don't need to be stored in the DB (because of the crypto behind them) but, ¿refresh_tokens shoul be stored?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could implement it either ways, both have their pros and cons.

1. send the refresh token as a JWT with longer expiry date.

   - can't revoke the refresh token when needed
   - do not need a DB to store the token
2. send as a random token and store it in DB and associate with user and client.

   - you can revoke the refresh token whenever you want
   - you will require a DB to store the token